# Convert special characters in to original form in python

Tags: python, string

Suppose I had a string for example:

```
>>>  stri = "日本"
>>>  res = stri
>>>  res
'\xe6\x97\xa5\xe6\x9c\xac'
```

Now I want to convert the result in `res` back to the form in `"日本"`.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker : Yes i had copied it from console, actually my intension is to convert back to its original form without using print function, is there anyway other than print function

Comment: How do you plan to use the string if you're not printing it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming that you're using Python 2.x on a UTF-8 console):

Nothing has been converted, and there is no need to convert anything back; what you're seeing is the internal representation of the string. Try `print`ing it.

```
>>>  stri = "日本"
>>>  stri
'\xe6\x97\xa5\xe6\x9c\xac'
>>> print(stri)
日本
```

To clarify:

If you enter the name of a Python variable in the console, the console will print the `repr` of that variable. If you want to print the variable in human-readable form, use `print` instead. There is no difference in the way the variable is stored, therefore there's nothing to convert.

Comment: Whether there is any way other than using print function?

Answer (score 1):

That is the expected behaviour - console doesn't print variable in unicode. If you actually print it out you'll see that the correct chars are still there. The console automatically uses repr on every variable before printing it out. You can verify that yourself by doing print(repr...)) like the example below:

```
>>> stri = "日本"
>>> stri
'\xe6\x97\xa5\xe6\x9c\xac'
>>> print stri
日本
>>> print repr(stri)
'\xe6\x97\xa5\xe6\x9c\xac'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Tim said, the characters haven't been converted.

[This article](http://pythoncentral.org/encoding-and-decoding-strings-in-python-2-x/) should help you understand what's happening